# How to use reverse proxy to load balance across large number of tcp applications

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, scalability

Imagine I have 100K tcp server applications (no HTTP at all) and each tcp server application uses a different port and spread across different machines. How can I use nginx or any reverse proxy to loadbalance across all the 100K tcp server applications?